# GetCommState failure with code 87

Tags: winapi, boost-asio, handle

GetCommState fails with error code 87.

Can this system call be used with any type of serial port? I have an RS422 USART card. Port can be configured as Sync or Async. I have it configured as Async and was using boost:asio. I noticed the failure while stepping through the code and ended up in the code below in a boost file. I took it out and put it in my main along with a call to CreateFile right before it. I get a good handle(handle is not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE). I can't get it to return successful. Any ideas? I called the serial card tech support and I was told this call should work.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std; // For memset.
DCB dcb;
//memset(&dcb, 0, sizeof(DCB));
SecureZeroMemory(&dcb, sizeof(DCB)); // tried this from a suggestion I saw online somewhere
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
if (!GetCommState(hDevice, &dcb))
{
  DWORD last_error = ::GetLastError();
  CloseHandle(hDevice);
  exit(1);
 // ec = boost::system::error_code(last_error,
 //   boost::asio::error::get_system_category());
//return ec;
}
```

Comment: this does not appear specific to Boost.Asio, can you add some other tags to get a wider audience viewing the question?

Comment: Hi Sam. I tried GetCommState which would be perfect. But I could not add that as a tag. I don't have enough status here. Boost.Asio is related because the call is embedded in one of the boost library files.

Answer (score 0):

If you were on a *NIX platform, check out /usr/include/errno.h (which probably has a #include for /usr/include/sys/errno.h) and see what matches up with your return code. Since you're on Windows, you'll have to hit up MSDN. Error code 87:

```
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER 87  One of the parameters was invalid.
```

I'd guess GetCommState() isn't liking your hDevice parameter. The call to SecureZeroMemory() shouldn't be necessary if you use memset(). Have you checked to see if all of the necessary parameters of dcb are set with respect to hDevice?

Comment: Sean, what you said about the parameters of dcb is somewhat correct. But because I don't have the technical background to give the proper answer, I will just comment yours and maybe someone else or you can give the proper answer to it. The card that I have has a special device driver. I had to set certain settings before I called GetCommState. Then it worked. So just retrieving a handle, then calling GetCommState did not work for me. I won't put in the sample code because the IOCTL parameters are device specific. It would be of no use to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'm sure someone will dig around and will find something useful with the `GetCommState` references.